# Create null sequences with gkmSVM for mouse genome mm10

Tags: r, svm, bioinformatics, bioconductor

Has anyone ever tried to generate null model of DNA sequences in mouse using the *gkmSVM* package? It works perfectly for human but for mouse it does not. I am wondering if any of you have never used this package for mice and had the same problem.

The error problem when I use the *genNullseqs* function is:

```
library(gkmSVM)
library(BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10)
library(BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.masked)
library(IRanges)

genome=BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.masked

fileBedBreaks="Rep1.intersec.Rep2.cov.major2.sort.uniq.bed"
fileFastaPos="Rep1.intersec.Rep2.cov.major2.all.sort.uniq.bed.pos.fa"
fileBedNeg="Rep1.intersec.Rep2.cov.major2.all.sort.uniq.Random.gkmSVM.bed"
fileFastaNeg="Rep1.intersec.Rep2.cov.major2.all.sort.uniq.Random.gkmSVM.fa"

genNullSeqs(inputBedFN=fileBedBreaks,nMaxTrials=5,xfold=2,genome=genome,
            outputPosFastaFN=fileFastaPos,outputBedFN=fileBedNeg,
            outputNegFastaFN=fileFastaNeg)
```

**Error**

```
Error in normalizeDoubleBracketSubscript(i, x, exact = exact) :
      subscript "TRF" matches no name
```